# regex: balancing "{}" in a complex regex (python)

Tags: python, regex

I try to extract information from a complex string with regex. I try to extract what in the first `{` an last `}` as the content. Unfortunately, I struggle with nested `{}`. How is it possible to deal with this ?

I think the key is to balance the `{}` over the all regex by I haven't been successful so far... See example below for parenthesis:
[Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)

```
import re

my_string = """
extend mineral Uraninite {
    kinetics {
        rate = -3.2e-08 mol/m2/s
        area = Uraninite
        y-term, species = Uraninite
        w-term {
            species = H[+]
            power = 0.37
        }
    }
    kinetics {
        rate = 3.2e-09 mol/m2/s
        area = Uraninite
        y-term, species = Uraninite
        w-term {
            species = H[+]
            power = 0.37
        }
    }
}
"""

regex = re.compile(
        r"extend\s+"
        r"(?:(?P<phase>colloid|mineral|basis|isotope|solid-solution)\s+)?"
        r"(?P<species>[^\n ]+)\s+"
        r"{(?P<content>[^}]*)}\n\s+}")
extend_list = [m.groupdict() for m in regex.finditer(my_string)]
```

So far, I got:

```
print(extended_list["content"])

"""
    kinetics {
        rate = -3.2e-08 mol/m2/s
        area = Uraninite
        y-term, species = Uraninite
        w-term {
            species = H[+]
            power = 0.37
"""
```

Appearly, I need to use the regex package [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) because re does not support recursion. Indeed, this seems to work:

```
import regex as re
pattern = re.compile(r"{(?P<content>((?:[^{}]|(?R))*))}")
extend_list2 = [m.groupdict() for m in pattern.finditer(read_data)]

print(extended_list2["content"])

"""
kinetics {
        rate = -3.2e-08 mol/m2/s
        area = Uraninite
        y-term, species = Uraninite
        w-term {
            species = H[+]
            power = 0.37
        }
    }
    kinetics {
        rate = 3.2e-09 mol/m2/s
        area = Uraninite
        y-term, species = Uraninite
        w-term {
            species = H[+]
            power = 0.37
        }
    }
"""
```

But inserting it in the main pattern does not work.

```
pattern = re.compile(
        r"extend\s+([^n]*)"
        r"(?:(?P<phase>colloid|mineral|basis|isotope|solid-solution)\s+)?"
        r"(?P<species>[^\n ]+)\s+"
        r"{(?P<content>((?:[^{}]|(?R))*))\}")
extend_list = [m.groupdict() for m in pattern.finditer(read_data)]
```

Comment: The `{` and `}` need to be escaped with backslash, i.e. use `\{`

Comment: Also look at [the `X` (aka `VERBOSE`) flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X), which allows you to format the regex in a structured form, even to include comments. For complex expressions that's definitely a plus.

Comment: Regexes can’t easily count nested bracketing except in limited cases - you’re better using a proper parser

Comment: Is `[^n]` a typo? Did you mean `[^\n]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the current regex can be written as

```py
rx = r"extend\s+(.*)(?:(?P<phase>colloid|mineral|basis|isotope|solid-solution)\s+)?(?P<species>\S+)\s+({(?P<content>((?:[^{}]++|(?4))*))})"
```

The `(?R)` is changed into a regex subroutine, `({(?P<content>((?:[^{}]++|(?4))*))})`. The group ID is Group 4 and the soubroutine declaration is thus `(?4)`. You can quickly test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/D52pNN/2).

The `[^n]*` looks like a typo, it matches zero or more non-`n` chars. I used `.*`, that matches zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

The `[^\n ]` looks like an attempt to match non-whitespace chunks, thus I suggest `\S` here.

Comment: Actually, it can be simplified to `rx = r"extend\s+(?:(?P<phase>colloid|mineral|basis|isotope|solid-solution)\s+)?(?P<species>[^\n ]+)\s+({(?P<content>((?:[^{}]++|(?3))*))})"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write simpler code with `pyparsing` to extract what in the first `{` and last `}` in `my_string`:

```py
import pyparsing as pp

pattern = pp.Regex(r'.*?(?={)') + pp.original_text_for(pp.nested_expr('{', '}'))
result = pattern.parse_string(my_string)[1][1:-1]
print(result)
```

* `pyparsing` can be installed by `pip install pyparsing`

##### Note:

If a pair of parentheses gets broken inside `{}` (for example `a{b{c}`, `a{b}c}`, etc), an unexpected result is obtained or `IndexError` is raised. So be careful. (See: [Python extract string in a phrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70953916/python-extract-string-in-a-phrase/70959340#70959340))